# HHVM 3.1.0 & PGSQL

Tags: postgresql, hhvm

I am having issues with getting the PGSQL extension working in HHVM 3.1.0, on Ubuntu Trusty 14.04 (LTS), with NGINX.

```
#hhvm --version
HipHop VM 3.1.0 (rel)
Compiler: tags/HHVM-3.1.0-0-g71ecbd8fb5e94b2a008387a2b5e9a8df5c6f5c7b
Repo schema: 88ae0db264d72ec2e2eb22ab25d717214aee568b
```

Following the instructions here, https://github.com/PocketRent/hhvm-pgsql I edit my /etc/hhvm/php.ini file, and add the following:

```
DynamicExtensionPath = /data/config/etc/hhvm/extensions/
DynamicExtensions {
    * = pgsql.so
}
```

but I get an error when starting HHVM :

```
 # service hhvm restart
 * Restarting HHVM FastCGI Daemon hhvm
 syntax error, unexpected JUNK, expecting $end or TC_SECTION or TC_LABEL or END_OF_LINE in /etc/hhvm/php.ini on line 13\n
 syntax error, unexpected JUNK, expecting $end or TC_SECTION or TC_LABEL or END_OF_LINE in /etc/hhvm/php.ini on line 13\n
```

My php.ini looks like this

```
; php options

; hhvm specific
hhvm.log.level = Warning
hhvm.log.always_log_unhandled_exceptions = true
hhvm.log.runtime_error_reporting_level = 8191
hhvm.mysql.typed_results = false


; hhvm.dynamicextensions.pgsql = /data/config/etc/hhvm/extensions/pgsql.so

DynamicExtensionPath = /data/config/etc/hhvm/extensions/
DynamicExtensions {
    * = pgsql.so
}
```

You can see I have also tried the following based on the info I have seen about moving from hdf to an ini file:

```
hhvm.dynamic_extensions.pgsql = /data/config/etc/hhvm/extensions/pgsql.so
```

which does not throw any errors on startup, but does not render true when running PHP code

```
if (extension_loaded('pgsql')) {
```

The pgsql.so comes from the pre-built binary here https://github.com/PocketRent/hhvm-pgsql/tree/releases/3.1.0/ubuntu/trusty, to ensure it matches the Ubunntu / HHVM version I am using.

Can anyone help out here and tell me what is going on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot currently load extensions into HHVM using the INI format (`hhvm.dynamic_extensions.pgsql` or `extension`). You have to use the Hdf format for this.

The easiest way to do this so that it works from both the web and the CLI is to create `/etc/hhvm/config.hdf` and add:

```
DynamicExtensionPath = /data/config/etc/hhvm/extensions
DynamicExtensions {
    * = pgsql.so
}
```

Then, edit `/etc/default/hhvm` and uncomment the `ADDITIONAL_ARGS` line and change it to `ADDITIONAL_ARGS="-c /etc/hhvm/config.hdf"`. Restart HHVM and it should then be picked up.

The CLI automatically tries to load this file, so you don't need to do anything extra there (unless you're passing in a `-c` option, then you'll need to pass in the `config.hdf` file too)

Answer (score 2):

As per the updated documentation (https://github.com/PocketRent/hhvm-pgsql), you can simply add a couple of lines to hhvm's PHP.INI in the latest versions of hhvm.

```
hhvm.dynamic_extension_path = /path/to/hhvm/extensions
hhvm.dynamic_extensions[pgsql] = pgsql.so
```

Comment: Should this /path/to/hhvm/extensions be owned by www-data user. It is the same user which is running hhvm master process? I am having hard time and it is not picking up pgsql.so from my path...

Comment: No. I simply created a folder named extensions within /etc/hhvm and placed my extensions in there e.g. ; extensions  
hhvm.dynamic_extension_path = /etc/hhvm/extensions
hhvm.dynamic_extensions[geoip] = geoip.so
hhvm.dynamic_extensions[pgsql] = pgsql.so - Keep in mind I've abandoned this extension for now as it's not even development ready for my needs.

Comment: It doesn't currently support Large Object (LOB) streaming, which Drupal 7's pgsql driver makes use of.